# How to determine the number of rows containing empty strings ("") in each column of a data.table?

Tags: r

I have a large data.table of several million rows. I have converted all the columns to factors and replaced all NAs with empty strings (""). I would like to determine the number of empty strings in each column, ideally in a memory efficient manner.

Comment: Do you mean you want only to change strings that are exactly ""? Not "   " and so on?

Comment: @Elin Yes, only ""

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution without packages would be:

```
apply(df, 2, function(x) sum(x == ""))
```

However, this is likely to be slow and you could take advantage of some of the libraries.

For instance, this is how the `dplyr` solution would look like:

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  summarise_all(funs(sum(. == "")))
```

However, if you're dealing with large data frames, you'll likely benefit from even faster `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x == ""))]
```

But let's not forget there can also be a leaner & faster `tidyverse` solution (compared to `dplyr`):

```
library(purrr)

map_int(df, function(x) sum(x == ""))
```

Who is the winner here?

I did a quick benchmark on a table with 400 000 rows and 26 columns, and `data.table` seems to be the fastest on average (the unit is milliseconds):

```
      expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval
     purrr  56.80567  58.76752  71.99501  64.61143  78.72492  199.9948   100
     dplyr  70.65627  73.17036  85.56228  79.73072  93.51717  194.7238   100
      base 689.97336 771.03395 830.39465 794.20452 881.38988 1116.8218   100
 datatable  57.83673  60.17200  70.97264  64.60314  78.89446  165.2100   100
```

However, `purrr` doesn't really lag behind, with a different run it could as well overtake `DT`. If you're already using one or the other, you'll be fine just sticking to it.

Comment: This will fail for datasets containing dates.

Comment: The OP says all the columns are factors

Comment: Understand. Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `colSums` from `base R`

```
colSums(df == "")
```